# incremental backup IMG files - Linux

Tags: linux, backup

I have been looking for a solution in LINUX to be able to get incremental backup of .img files (KVM) for the past two weeks and I tried almost everything I could get from searching in google ( Rdiffbackup, Attic, Rsync, Rsnapshot, Bacula, Areca Backup,etc.., you name it!) but still could not find a solution.

Basically I want something like an agent to run in the hardware node of the VMs and detect if an image is changed and be able to read inside the img file and copy the new section(s) only to the original img file which is backed up on the first run and to have a main backup machine which all the backups come into it.
I do not need any web interface(not necessarily) and it has to be under LINUX.

Would appreciate any suggestion or help on this.

Thank you

Comment: http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/IncrementalBackup but not quite what Veeam offers.

Comment: What was not working for you in the solutions ruled out? It seems that rsync would be the best bet for you...

Comment: @Fox Rsync could not realize that which part of img file is change and when time stamp of the img file changes, it copies the whole img file again

Comment: It is exactly what rsync does (copies only changed parts of file), but to do that, it has to read and checksum the whole file on both sides. So disk i/o is the same, but network traffic is less.

Comment: @Fox even for .img files? if so, how can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using LVM (optionally with thin provisioning) along with [lvmsync](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/lvmsync), but then I'm biased, having written lvmsync for this exact situation.

If that doesn't suit, the [qemu incremental backup support](http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/IncrementalBackup) (as mentioned in a comment by @HBruijn) in newer versions of qemu is available, if you don't mind running bleeding edge code.  Unfortunately, the qcow2 image format doesn't allow the kind of "live point-in-time snapshot" feature that would be needed to implement the sync process you'd like.  The VMDK format does, and I wrote [vmdksync](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/vmdksync) to handle that, but I don't know if qemu's VMDK support is suitably advanced to deal with it (I wrote it to migrate off VMWare servers, and I've never tested it against qemu).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can not have the VM ( or its service)to be down and copy. I am looking for something to backup from live without stopping

Comment: Yeeeesssss... that's what my suggestions will provide.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities.

1. rsync. It does what you expect it to do, but to do so, it has to read whole file on both ends, compute checksums and transfer the changes. If you are not using rsync remotely (networked filesystem for example), you need to disable whole-file transfer. (`--no-whole-file`)
2. LVM snapshots + lvmsync as suggested by @womble
3. Filesystem that supports snapshots and incremental backups (like btrfs (still not recommended for production), or ZFS).
4. DRBD - works as an online "RAID1". Does not work as an archive - if anything gets deleted on master, it is lost immediately on slave as well. But you have the latest data in case of hardware failure. (possible hack is to enable synchronization only at certain times, but i'd not recommend that) Just keep in mind, that most filesystems can not be mounted on both ends.
5. Combination of 2/3 and 4 (DRBD+LVM snapshots, or DRBD+ZFS) - gives you the best of both worlds. Online "RAID" across machines, and snapshotting the backing device on backup server to keep an archive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried DRBD but could not make it happen, I am looking at qemu now to see if I can make it to work.